# Como cambiar raiz de default de un proyecto de dockerfile

Tags: php, docker, phalcon

Buen día

Tengo el siguiente dockerfile que instala un proyecto de php con el framework de phalcon. Mi duda es, que tengo que mover al dockerfile para que la ruta para entrar al api no sea la de default, me gustaría agregarla dentro de un directorio "miProyecto".

Ejemplo como corre actualmente: servidor:8080/api/saludar

Y como quiero que corra: servidor:8080/miProyecto/api/saludar

```
FROM harbor.io/library/composer:2.0.14 AS dependencies
WORKDIR /pkg
COPY composer.json .
RUN composer update --no-scripts --no-dev

FROM harbor.io/library/php-rac:7.4.26 AS source
WORKDIR /src
COPY --from=dependencies /pkg .
COPY . .
RUN rm -f .htaccess .gitignore Dockerfile && rm -rf logs/ .git/

FROM harbor.io/library/php-rac:7.4.26
WORKDIR /app
ADD http://gitlab.io/oc/docker/containers/-/raw/61aac45359f75fd5fe8c46b705e0a9e43755f2e3/rac/nginx/site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
COPY --from=source /src .
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu dockerfile antes de último paso agregas

```
RUN mkdir -p /app/miProyecto
```

El último paso cambias como

```
COPY --from=source /src /app/miProyecto
```